# How to execute/hold a command in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to see if it's possible to execute a command from a variable

Example of what I'm going for:

```
variable = print ("something")
print ("Done")
```

And then be able to print that by writing the variable name after this.
Example:

```
variable
```

but when I try the output is:

```
something
Done
```

I know you could do this by just writing the thing you want to print in the variable, but I would like to use this for other commands.

Comment: Functions. You're looking for functions. Your `variabel` should be a function.

Comment: I've accepted the edit @Peter Dolan so you have no reason to keep the downvote.

Comment: @Mr.Blue I did not downvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you define functions or in this short case you can wrap it into a lambda-function:

```
print_that = lambda: print("something")
print_that()
print("done")
```

You call it with the `()`. The `print_that` would be that what you called `variabel`. With a function you can execute more commands:

```
def print_that():
    print("something")
    print("something else")
```

Comment: Yes ty I will accept it as soon as I can

Comment: One complaint... `lambda` builds anonymous function objects and is used when you _don't_ want to assign the function to a variable. The first part of your answer is promoting bad habits. If you want to assign a function object to a variable... that's what `def` is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to call any already defined function with some fixed arguments.

```
from functools import partial
print_something = partial(print, "something")

# Use () to call as a normal function
print_something() # prints "something"

# You can pass more arguments later
print_something("another thing") # prints "something another thing"
```